# Coroutine not Working inside OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I saw some similar questions but literally I can't see where I'm doing wrong. Basicly I need a break before level fail.

```
public static int point;
public static int health;

void Awake()
{
    point = 0;
    health = 3;
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "coin")
    {
        point ++;

        EventManager.OnCoinPickUp.Invoke();
        Coin.SharedInstance.DisposeOnTrigger(other);
    }
    else if(other.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        health --;

        EventManager.OnPreLevelFail.Invoke();

        if(health == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeFail());
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitBeforeFail()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1.5f );
    EventManager.OnLevelFail.Invoke();
}
```

It doesn't work so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Is there a chance that EventManager.OnPreLevelFail.Invoke() has code that increases health above 0?

Comment: Use prints or break points and see if your `if`s are entering. The code looks fine, but you gotta make sure it is entering where it should. Also a quick tip, instead of doing `other.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle"`, use `other.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle")`.
Also, for security reasons, use `if(health <= 0)`, just in case this trigger enters more than once, and take care to not call your `OnLevelFail` more than once.

Comment: So you mean that OnLevelFail is being invoked immediately after your health has reached 0? Or that the scene changes immediatelly?

Comment: @VladStoyanoff It's the scene. The scene changes immediatelly.

Comment: @bartol44 I don't think so because the line below about scene management works. It's just the coroutine before that not working.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your nice tips. I have already started using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is, you are starting the coroutine, it does, in fact, wait 1.5 seconds, and after that OnLevelFail is invoked. Your problem comes from the fact that the code for changing the scene is not inside the coroutine. So the coroutine is executed but immediately after that the scene changes. If you put the code for the scene inside the coroutine you won't have problems and the scene will change in 1.5 seconds.

You see, starting a coroutine does exactly and only that - starts it. It does not wait before continuing with the following code. The waiting happens inside the coroutine itself.